# Filtering com_content in the backend by url in Joomla 3.3.1

Tags: component, url, administration, com-content, article-manager

I am trying to filter the article manager in the backend via the url like:

> index.php?option=com_content&filter_category_id=18

but it doesn't seem to work. 
Instead it gives me a warning:

> Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /libraries/framework/Joomla/Registry/Registry.php on line 428

Are there any changes on how we could filter the component, or there is a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the method of doing this has now changed. I have checked this method and it works perfectly. I cant break it at all

Here is an example using published

> index.php?option=com_content&view=articles&filter[published]=1

You can also use

- [filter]level
- [filter]author_id

etc

in fact everything that is in the search tools on the article view can be preset using the URL, just get its ID using Google dev tools!

This may be obvious, but just feel like I need to complete the answer in case anyone else looks, but you You can also stack the filters, i.e

> ```
> index.php?option=com_content&view=articles&filter[category_id]=2&filter[level]=1
> ```

Comment: Does this work for you in Joomla 3.3.1? I forgot the view on my question, but I have tried with the view on the real scenario. It still doesn't work on this install and it is almost a fresh one. I will try it on another one as well...

Comment: Yup just tried on a brand new 3.1.1 install, works fine

Comment: I was also able to replicate your exact error message by leaving out the view

Comment: OK, created a new category. Was given the ID of 8, created a new article with that category and then went to `{website}/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=articles&filter_category_id=8` and voila the search filter changed to the new category, and just the one article was listed

Comment: this is a 3.1.1 install I did yesterday downloaded fresh from the Joomla website

Comment: OMG! and all of a sudden.. it doesnt work. I am pulling up URL's in the history that worked only mins ago and they now show that error. Thanks for that, just as I am about to go to bed!!! Will revisit tomorrow, this may be one for the bug squad after all!

Comment: Interesting, I switched over to Safari (from Chrome) and initially.. again the filters worked as described above, but as soon as I click on 'Search Tools / Clear' those filters stop working until I actually log out and back into Joomla Admin.

Comment: and my last comment before bed, this error also occurs on Joomla 3.2

Comment: Reported on joomla bug tracker with 100% method of reproduction [link] (http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=33963&start=0)

Comment: good to know that is not only me

Comment: Final answer submitted and tested. Use new filter convention as detailed in answer

Comment: Hey there, I added a new answer to this question to address filtering on with multiple values. E.g. filtering articles on many categories.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the Joomla filters are allowing multiple selections, e.g. in `com_content` articles list we can filter using multiple categories, the way to achieve the filtering with a _GET query string is like below:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=articles&filter[category_id][]=105&filter[category_id][]=146
```

Essentially, we need to convert the desired filter to an array (when it applies) and then assign multiple.

```
&filter[category_id][]=105&filter[category_id][]=146
```