# getUserStateFromRequest variable become empty if name starts with '.filter.'

Tags: joomla-3.x, variable

In my view.html.php I set UserState Variables. One of this variables is set like this:

```
$app->setUserState('com_mycomponent.modelname'.'.filter.status', 1);
```

When I try to get the variable in the model via populateState function

```
$status = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.status', 'filter_status', null);
```

`$status` is empty.

In the layout default.php I have integrated a Joomla search tools bar with:

echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default', array('view' => $this));

Everything is done fine, execept I do a reload on the page, or I choose another option of the filter. To be more concret, I load the page, afterwards I select one of the filter options, I can do that one time good. If I choose another value of the same filter, or reload the page with F5, than the following error come up:

Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in D:\websites\etiral2015\libraries\framework\Joomla\Registry\Registry.php on line 428

What does that mean?

When I change '.filter.status' to anything else eg. `.filte.status` or `.filterstatus`, $status gets the right value.

So, why is it not possible to set UserState Variables starting with `.filter.` , like Joomla does with `.filter.search`?

I integrated the Joomla 3 SearchTools Bar in the layout, with a filter field which is located in `component->models->forms->xxxx.xml` and it is called `status`. But also removing this filter field, does not help to set the UserState variable called `.filter.status`.

It seems that the new Joomla filter bar in the form is responsible for this mistake.

The last two stack entries of the Joomlas integrated failure debugger, shows me, that the setting of the userState variable in the view.html.php won't be accepted anymore and that this is responsible for the problem.

```
Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in D:\home\joomla\libraries\framework\Joomla\Registry\Registry.php on line 428

11  ......

12  0.2121  4313344 JApplicationCms->setUserState( )    ..\view.html.php:50

13  0.2121  4313344 Joomla\Registry\Registry->set( )    ..\cms.php:1047
```

Furthermore, new settings of userState variables cannot be done, also not in other views with other userState variables. This problem exists until I logout from the session. After a new login, everything seems to be clear, until I come to the procedure I described.

Finally this leads in a security whole of my site, because if this userState filters cannot be set, users can have access to data which they are not permitted to see.

Joomla Version 3.3.6

Comment: new thread opened under http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/joomla-search-filter-tool-bar-attempt-to-assign-property-of-non-object-line-42

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/filtering-com-content-in-the-backend-by-url-in-joomla-3-3-1 seems kinda related?

Comment: @Perino - Please update your current question rather than asking a new one.

Comment: Please show your layout file. Do you have a `filter_status` field there?

Comment: @DmitryRekun: No, I dont have a filter_status field in the layout file. I have a separeted file called filter_myview.xml therefore, additionally to my layout file. Do I need both?

Comment: Ah this is a search tools you are using. I do not know much about this tool :( I am still using old style filters in my extensions.

Comment: Yes, I did it as add on, because it looks comfortable on the first sight. But it seems that sometimes there are complications with the new tools and features of the Joomla Framework (maybe you remember the problem with the button toolbar). But maybe there is something wrong from my side?

Comment: Is there any chance you can show your view.html.php and your model's code?