# Joomla search filter tool bar - attempt to assign property of non-object line 428

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, variable

In my view.html.php I set UserState Variables. One of this variables will be set like this:

```
$app->setUserState('com_mycomponent.modelname'.'.filter.status', 1);
```

In the layout default.php I have integrated a Joomla search tools bar with:

```
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default', array('view' => $this));
```

Everything is done fine, execept I do a reload on the page, or I choose another option of the filter. To be more concret, I load the page, afterwards I select one of the filter options, I can do that one time good. If I choose another value of the same filter, or reload the page with F5, than the following error come up:

Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in D:\websites\etiral2015\libraries\framework\Joomla\Registry\Registry.php on line 428

What does that mean?

The last two stack entries of the Joomlas integrated failure debugger, shows me, that the setting of the userState variable in the view.html.php won't be accepted anymore and that this is responsible for the problem.

```
12  0.2121  4313344 JApplicationCms->setUserState( )    ..\view.html.php:50

13  0.2121  4313344 Joomla\Registry\Registry->set( )    ..\cms.php:1047
```

Furthermore, new settings of userState variables cannot be done, also not in other views with other userState variables. This problem exists until I logout from the session. After a new login, everything seems to be clear, until I come to the procedure I described.

Finally this leads in a security whole of my site, because if this userState filters cannot be set, users can have access to data which they are not permitted to see.

Joomla Version 3.3.6

Comment: @Perino please stop to duplicate questions. Thank you.

Comment: For me this problems were different, because these are two different situations, and maybe they will result from the same causation. Because of your intervention, I adopted now the other thread. I integrated major parts of this one, hopefully that this two situations can be understand. This thread I will delete shortly. Thank you.