# Resetting 'view all users' back to 10 per page

Tags: administrator, user

I have approx 14,000 users on my Joomla website. I wondered what would happen if I tried to view all the users on one page.

Predictably, it wouldn't let me view all the users and now gives me a white screen. 
I can't seem to access the users page at all:

```
administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=users
```

How do I change the settings so that I can load the users page again and only see 10 users at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing all 14000 records in one table list on the browser, is almost impossible. It will be a heavy duty for the browser itself, apart from the query's memory consumption on the server level, which most likely will lead to a php fatal error.

### How to reset:

#### 1. Logout & re-Login

To reset the setting, simply log-out and re-login.
The User Manager list should be reset to its default.

#### 2. Filters on the url

You can also force the user manager list to show less users/page, by setting a limit on the query with manually adding parameters on the url:

```
administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=users&list[limit]=10
```

Some more info about using filters on the urls in the admin of Joomla you can find here:
**[Filtering com_content in the backend by url in Joomla 3.3.1](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/filtering-com-content-in-the-backend-by-url-in-joomla-3-3-1)**

Answer (score 3):

You can try few things :

1. Deleting sessions table data
2. clearing cache from admin backend
3. Try to add &list[limit]=5 to the URL so it will prevent loading all
   the users.
4. clear browsers cache.

   I hope it will work :)

Comment: Thanks for some really helpful suggestions. In the end logging in and out again worked just fine but all of these might be really helpful for next time I decide to experiment!

Answer (score 0):

A white screen means there's a PHP error.

Seeing as you're trying to load 14,000 rows from the `#__users` table, which then also loads 14,000+- users from the `#__user_usergroup_map` tables, you're trying to pull data from a minimum of 28,000 table rows.

s you can imagine, this is qute a lot, therefore I assume the error is related to PHP's memory limit or the max execution time.

In the Joomla Global Configuration, you can set error reporting to a higher level which will show you the error rather than a white screen.

Comment: Thanks Lodder the tip about viewing the error messages is a good one I shall bear in mind next time I decide to try experimenting!